# App Store Submission - Hi-Res Screenshots in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store-connect

I've searched through the iTunes Connect Developer Guide 6.1 - but can't seem to find anything about this.

I've just completed entering the meta-data into iTunes Connect for a new app. This app runs on iPod and iPhone and has graphics optimized for the Retina display, so it has @2x images for all graphics.

I prepared 5 screenshots to load into iTunes Connect (5 at 480x320 for the non-Retina displays and 5 at 920x640 for the Retina display devices). I expected that for each low-res screenshot I would need to load an identical version in hi-res. .. but, when I tried to upload the screenshots in iTunes Connect, iTunes Connect only allowed 5 screenshots to be uploaded. I decided to upload the hi-res versions and did not upload the low-res versions.

Questions: Am I missing something? Is there some option in iTunes Connect to upload low and hi-resolution screenshots? Page 52 of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide 6.1](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) stipulates the hi-res screenshot dimensions for Retina display compatible apps, but I'm perplexed about how to upload both the low and hi-res versions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything. Downscaling has to happen *anyway*, since the screenshots aren't shown at full size on iPhone/iPod (and presumably iPad doesn't show full-size iPad screenshots, though it might show full-size 1x iPhone screenshots).

Similarly, the icon displayed on the device's App Store appears to be resized from the (up to) 512x512 icon you upload, instead of just using the one in your app — this lets you put stuff like "50% off" in the App Store icon without it showing on device (I'm not sure what Apple's views are on this, but I don't think they particularly disapprove).

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for the response. It didn't occur to me that the screenshots are not used at native resolution.

Comment: iPhone screenshots are used at native resolution on iPad/iTunes, I think, but that's about it.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, whatever format you choose (480x320 or 920x640) it will show the exact same on the App Store on the iPhone. 
Beware of not mixing up different formats because if you do, although it will show them all on the iPad or in iTunes, it will only show images that the source is 920x640 on the iPhone 4 (retina display) and 480x320 source screenshot on older models.
Note also that this is a way to segregate what you wan to show to one or another, but you only have 5 slots to split among the two, that's a fact ;-)

Comment: I never realized this - did you determine this experimentally, or is this behavior documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Also, I would recommend since I am having this issue right now, to make your screenshot jpeg and exactly 72 ppi. Ai or other software somehow export an image at 72,09 ppi. Don't ask me why, I don't know... But, I do know that in addition to the full "exact" size, you should name your screenshot very simply. For example: Screen1, Screen 2, etc... I made the error of the "web-designer" and it turns out Apple's servers where not happy to see coming an "App-Cooker-Welcome-On-The-App-Board". Result >>> Only two screnshots showed up on five uploaded and after 12 hours, it is still the case... My best advice: be prepared and upload your screenshot a long time before your App goes out!